# VectorPlot with unitsize vectors

Tags: plotting, vector

I want to plot a vector field in which vectors are unite vectors(I want to
show just direction of the vectors).
I used vector Plot as below:

```
u = (x (y^2/(x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2));
v =  (y (y^2/(x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^(1/2));
VectorPlot[Boole[x^2 + y^2 > 1.5] {u, v}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

but it considers the size of vectors.
Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Look up `VectorScale`.

Answer (score 1):

```
u = beta (x (-1 + 3 y^2/(x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2)) /. beta -> 1;
v = (y (-1 + 3 y^2/(x^2 + y^2))/(x^2 + y^2)^(3/2));

VectorPlot[Boole[x^2 + y^2 > 1.5] {u, v}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 VectorScale -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Different sizes, "but not too much"

```
VectorPlot[Boole[x^2 + y^2 > 1.5] {u, v}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 VectorScale -> {Large, Automatic, Exp[#5] &},
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0.02],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: is there any way to use different sizes for vectors but the difference is not too much?

Comment: please edit your answer because I have edited the question. So I can chose it as correct

Comment: which parameter controls "too much"?

Comment: `Exp[#5]&]` - but there are endless possibilities with `VectorScale`

Comment: to make the difference more clear, should i increase 5?

Comment: No, `#5` is inbuilt and means "scale by Norm[fx, fy]" - you can also change the sizes by varying your `beta` parameter